# How to format time to 2 digit numbers?

Tags: java, date, time, format

I couldn't find any specialized answers. 
Here's the code:

```
        LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("[i][" + t.getHour() + ":" + t.getMinute()+ ":" +t.getSecond() + "] "
                + usr + " typed: " + cmd);
```

The output now looks like this:

```
[i][15:8:4] XY typed: test
```

What I want is to format it to make it look like this:

```
[i][15:08:04] XY typed: test
```

Comment: @Reimeus not really, this is for a telegram bot and I'd like to keep it like this, at least for now

Comment: BTW, if you are only using the time part, why not use `LocalTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: I'm pretty much beginner, someone helped me with creating this code. I was looking at that thread previously, marked as answer, and I couldn't find it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, good point, on the other hand there’s also sometimes a point in not throwing date-time information away prematurely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Tip: Most any basic date-time question has already been asked and answered here in Stack Overflow. Always search thoroughly before posting.